# Swiss Zero-Coupon Bond Yield Curve Data

Tags: fixed-income, zero-coupon

I am trying to access the Swiss Zero-Coupon Yield Curve Data. I know that the Swiss National Bank provides this data, as noted on the 8th Page of [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjABahUKEwjZwfGU_4fGAhUHUZIKHUIzDdo&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.alexandria.unisg.ch%2Fpublications%2F222514&ei=N655VZnKNoeiyQTC5rTQDQ&usg=AFQjCNFWwIzJGC-u0MK9Kqs5qoBlSHKh1g) under Section 3.2. However, I am for the life of me unable to find it and was wondering if someone on here has possibly accessed it at some point.

My apologies for asking this sort of question again. However, I don't have access to a Bloomberg Terminal and hence cannot make use of their Zero-Coupon Yield Curve Data.

I have also contacted the Swiss National Bank about this but they have yet to respond and I don't know if they will.

Thank You

Comment: Do you have any primer brokers? This kind of data is easily obtained from the research websites of JPM, MS, BarCap, etc.

Comment: http://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/bonds/overview_en.html

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki Thanks. But I don't see any Zero-Coupon Yield Curve Data there specifically. Were you able to find such data on the site?

Comment: http://www.six-swiss-exchange.com/bonds/explorer_en.html#srtBy=ShortName&savedHash=true

Answer (score 4):

In case you're still looking:

https://data.snb.ch/en/topics/ziredev#!/cube/rendoblid

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I'm not sure but no problem! It's the correct data and I hope the original poster and others find it useful.